# Using the same 3 lines of code to print many lines

Tags: python

The code below prints the text welcome, letter by letter every 0.1 seconds.

```
welcome = ("Welcome")

for character in welcome:
    print (character, end = "", flush = True)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Usually if I wanted to print several things (in this case Welcome and Hello) I would do this:

```
welcome = ("Welcome")
hello = ("Hello")

for character in welcome:
    print (character, end = "", flush = True)
    sleep(0.1)

for character in hello:
    print (character, end = "", flush = True)
    sleep(0.1)
```

But it is not efficient to be typing this every time I want a new line because it wastes a lot of time and space.

```
for character in hello:
        print (character, end = "", flush = True)
        sleep(0.1)
```

Is there a way I can somehow use only one of these

```
for character in hello:
            print (character, end = "", flush = True)
            sleep(0.1)
```

to print many different lines like this:

```
hello = ("How are You")
welcome = ("Welcome")
nice = ("Awesome")
```

Comment: Write a function?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because honestly come on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over an array, in which you store all messages:

```
from time import sleep

hello = ("How are You")
welcome = ("Welcome")
nice = ("Awesome")

messages = [hello, welcome, nice]
for message in messages:
    for character in message:
        print (character, end = "", flush = True)
        sleep(0.1)
    print('')
```

the output looks like that:

> How are You
>
> Welcome
>
> Awesome

Answer (score 0):

just create a function like that

```
welcome = "Welcome"
hello = "Hello"

list = [welcome,hello]

def my_function(word):
    for character in word:
        print(character, end="", flush=True)
        sleep(0.1)

def my_function_list(list):
    for word in list:
        my_function(word)

my_function_list(list)
```

Comment: you need to put some empty print function after your loop as well, to not print everything in a single line

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function. Like this one:

```py
def print_char_by_char(word): 
    for character in word:  
        print (character, end = "", flush = True)  
        sleep(0.1)
```

And then use it:

```py
print_char_by_char("How are You")
print_char_by_char("Welcome")
print_char_by_char("Awesome")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define and reuse one or two functions, check the following code:

```py
def fancy_print(text):
    [print_and_wait(c) for c in text]

def print_and_wait(char):
    from time import sleep
    print(char, end='', flush=True)
    sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello = "How are You"
    fancy_print(hello)

    welcome = "Welcome"
    fancy_print(welcome)

    nice = "Awesome"
    fancy_print(nice)
```

Comment: you need to put some empty print function after your loop as well, to not print everything in a single line

Comment: This can be resolved by adding a new line character `\n` to the input text and the original questions mentions not such thing as mandatory new line every time a text is displayed

Comment: ...every time I want a new line... :)